# How to find the changed delta value for update transaction after rollback is done in transaction log in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

I am trying to understand the internals of tranaction log of mssql. 
I do a following transaction

```
Begin TRANSACTION
update xyz1 set a=6
Rollback TRANSACTION
```

Initially value of column 'a' is 5 . So the result of the transaction was found to be as shown below using

```
SELECT 
    Operation, [RowLog Contents 0], [RowLog Contents 1, AllocUnitName, [Page ID],
    [Slot ID], [Offset in Row],[Transaction ID]
FROM 
    sys.fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)

operation         rowcontent0  row content 1     AllocUnitName  Page ID        Slot ID  Offset     
LOP_BEGIN_XACT  NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL              NULL  
LOP_MODIFY_ROW  0x01    0x06        dbo.xyz1        0001:0000022e   0   4  
LOP_MODIFY_ROW  0x  0x01        dbo.xyz1        0001:0000022e   0   4  
LOP_ABORT_XACT  NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL              NULL
```

As we see from above values that data is changed from 1 to 6 and again its changed to 1 since roll back has occured.

Then to get the memory information i use the below command, where 558(22e) is page id which can be found in the above table

```
dbcc traceon(3604)
dbcc page(lumrecon,1,558,3)
```

go to slot 0 and rowoffset 4 to see the data changed

```
00000000:   10000800 01000000 010000†††††††††††††...........
```

We observe from the memory dump that we find only value of rolled back transaction ie a =1.

But my question is how do we find the original value i.e 6 in the tranaction that occured. Is this the microsoft behaviour of not intentionally writing info into the log or is there any way ?? please suggest .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The "0x06" in the log row

```
LOP_MODIFY_ROW  0x01    0x06        dbo.xyz1
```

is the new value written to the column. Since the transaction is rolled back the information about the "6" now is only in the log, not in the page buffer (memory). In memory there is always the latest value for the row (including unfinished transactions), potentially protected by a logical lock and sometimes a latch.